# How to create a regexp that catches everything that isn't a pure number

Tags: regex

I have a string made of many lines containing pure numbers and words that may contain digits, for example:

```
1 11 blabla12_ho5::blabla14_ho4
```

I want to get rid of the words and leave only the pure numbers, so that the result will be:

```
1 11
```

I've tried the regexp "`[^ ]*[^\d][^ ]*`" to catch the words and remove them by using `regsub` to an empty string. but it catches the second number as well and returns:

```
1
```

What is a correct regexp for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The regexp that managed to catch a word that contains special characters as well as letters and numbers without finding pure numbers is:

```
\b[^ ]*[^\d ]+[^ ]*
```

Answer (score 2):

Word boundary followed by series of digits followed by word boundary:

```
\b(\d+)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is closer to this:

```
/\D(\d+)\D/g
```

Answer (score 0):

catch number and alphabet(no include pure number): `\b(?!\d+\b)\w+\b`
catch pure number: `\b(\d+)\b`

Answer (score 0):

Different RegEx parsers will use slightly different syntaxes. What you trying to do this regex in?

The answer to your question lies in greedy vs. lazy matching.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tangental to your question since you are asking about RegEx's, but for what you're doing, if all you want to do is take the first two columns and you are using Linux, you could do something simple like

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1-2 myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use grep:

```
echo "1 11 blabla12_ho5::blabla14_ho4" | grep -E -o "\b[[:digit:] ]+\b"
1 11
```